# jQuery sortable table rows - rows change height after sorting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to use jQuery UI sortable on a table, and am experiencing a problem. Once i drop a row the height is not exactly what it was before. It gets smaller and the rows don't use up the whole table for some reason.

What could I do to prevent this? It is very visible when only 2 rows are in the table, but barely noticeable when many rows are available, still I would like to have control over this.

**EDIT:**

This is about what happens in the sortable table, not the result table.

Apparently this problem only occurs in webkit, but not in Mozilla or IE.

**Demo:**

http://jsbin.com/ucopun/66/edit

**Here is my js Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //sort
    $("#myTable").on('click', '.up, .down', function(event) {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        if ($(this).is(".up")) {
            row.insertBefore(row.prev());
        } else {
            row.insertAfter(row.next());
        }
        row.fadeOut();
        row.fadeIn();
    });
    //fix dd width of rows
    $(function() {
        var fixHelper = function(e, ui) {
            ui.children().each(function() {
                $(this).width($(this).width());
            });
            return ui;
        };

        $("#myTable tbody").sortable({
            helper: fixHelper
        });
        $("#myTable tbody").disableSelection();
    });

    //buttons  
    var savebtn = "<div class=\"save\">Save</div>";

    var editbtn = "<div class=\"edit\">Edit</div>";

    var removebtn = "<div class=\"remove\">Remove</div>";

    var upbtn = "<a class=\"up\">up</a><a class=\"down\">down</a>";

    $("#target").click(function() {
        //add  
        var speise = $(".addnew").val();
        var beschr = $(".addnew2").val();
        $('#myTable tr:last').after('<tr class="frst"><td class="content"><span class="speise">' + speise + '</span><span class="beschr">' + beschr + '</span></td><td class="btns">' + removebtn + '</td><td class="btns">' + editbtn + upbtn + '</td></tr>');
    });
    $("#myTable").on('click', '.remove', function(event) {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });

    //edit
    $("#myTable").on('click', '.edit', function(event) {
        var speise = $(this).closest("tr").find(".speise").text();
        var beschr = $(this).closest("tr").find(".beschr").text();
        $(this).closest("tr").find(".content").html('<input class="sp" value="' + speise + '"/><br><input class="be" value="' + beschr + '"/>');

        $(this).parent().html(savebtn);

    });

    //save
    $("#myTable").on('click', '.save', function(event) {
        var speise = $(this).closest("tr").find(".sp").val();
        var beschr = $(this).closest("tr").find(".be").val();
        $(this).closest("tr").find(".content").html('<span class="speise">' + speise + '</span><span class="beschr">' + beschr + '</span>');

        $(this).parent().html(editbtn);

    });
    //result
});

$("button").click(function() {
    var data = "";
    $("#myTable tr td:first-child").each(function() {
        data += "<tr><td>" + $(this).text() + "</td></tr>";
    });
    $(".result").html(data);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="content">
      <span class="speise">SPEISE</span>
      <span class="beschr">BESCHREIBUNG</span>
    </td>
    <td class="btns">
      <div class="remove">REMOVE</div></td>
    <td class="btns">
      <div class="edit">edit</div>
      <a class="up">up</a>
    <a class="down">down</a>
    </td>

  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="content">
            <span class="speise">SPEISE</span>
      <span class="beschr">BESCHREIBUNG2</span>

      </td>
    <td class="btns">
      <div class="remove">REMOVE</div></td>
          <td class="btns">
      <div class="edit">edit</div>

     <a class="up">up</a>
    <a class="down">down</a>
      </td>

  </tr>

</table>
  Speise<br>
  <input class="addnew" type="text" id="name" />
  <br>Beschreibung <br>
  <input class="addnew2" type="text" id="name" />
<div id="target">Add</div>
<div id="target2">Add2</div>
  <button>Result me</button>
  <div><table class="result"></table></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    border:solid black 1px;
    height:200px;
}
td {
  border:solid 1px red;
}
#target {
    width:50px;
    border:solid red 2px;
}
.remove {
  color:red;
    font-wieght:bold;
}
.result {
  border:solid red 2px;
}

td span, a {
  display:block;
}
a {cursor:pointer;}
tr {
  cursor:move;
}
.btns {
  cursor:auto;
}
```

Also if there is a simple way to do drag & drop sorting without jQuery UI but only with jQuery I would appreciate a link, as I feel this problem, and many others are created by jQuery UI.

Comment: you can sort tables using plain JS, i usually sort my tables in php at the server and print them,u can use ajax to avoid reloading , just my way taught

Comment: i want to have drag and drop though. i allready have a pure jquery solution using up/down buttons, but i want d&d in addition.

Comment: drag and drop is a bit harder, yet u can use pure js instead of jquery ui, IMHO it is an overkill

Comment: yes, i would like to do it without UI but everything i can find is for UI...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use fixed height for your table tr:

```
#myTable tr{height:100px}
```

[SEE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ucopun/70/edit)

Comment: if you look closely there is still the very same problem, but less noticable

Comment: In chrome windows 7, i have no more problem. BTW, you should remove fixed table height (height:200px).  http://jsbin.com/ucopun/71/edit

Comment: look closely at the bottom of the table after reordering, then click "run" and see the difference in space. im running chrome on win7 too

Comment: Seems like a bug in webkit for css property display:table-row of tr element. Tested your code in FireFox, and works fine. Sorry, cannot find any fix.

Comment: Find a workaround but need more test: http://jsbin.com/ucopun/85/edit  Basically, you need to redraw the table element but seems to have some new issues using up/down button

Comment: this looks like its working! what issues are you facing with the up/down i couldnt find any.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `height:200px;` from `table` and it will be ok.

for getting result table with same height do the following:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var data = "";
    $("#myTable tr td:first-child").each(function(){
        data+= '<tr style="height:' + $("#myTable tr").height() + '"><td>' + $(this).text() + '</td></tr>';
    });
    $(".result").html(data);
});
```

than you will have same height on result..

played on your jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ucopun/73/edit

Comment: the problem is not the result table but the sortable table

Comment: @user1721135 as showed on my answer just go `table` in your **css** and delete fixed `height:200px;`

Comment: thx but the problem still occurs, see anwser and commets on the first answer

Comment: @user1721135 ok i guess i found the solution try appending all html by jquery like this http://jsbin.com/ucopun/78/edit and please inform me of any changes.

Comment: this doesnt run, i changed it to html(), but still the same problem http://jsbin.com/ucopun/80/edit

Comment: @user1721135 sorry about that i also added result here: http://jsbin.com/ucopun/81/edit

Comment: thx, same problem though. apparently this is a webkit bug rather then js issue, it works fine in IE and firefox.

Comment: @user1721135 yea i've seen it at last. I tried many times and it worked on firefox - ie - opera but when it comes to chrome - maxthon - safari it acts differently..